# Set-Cookie error: Browser doesn't save cookie despite successful response

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, cookies, nestjs

I'm working on an Angular/NestJS application, and I've hit a roadblock with cookie management. When I log in through my Angular frontend, the server responds with a Set-Cookie header containing the JWT token. However, the cookie isn't being saved in the browser, and I can't figure out why.

I've confirmed the Set-Cookie header is present in the response using the browser's DevTools. The backend is set up with CORS to accept credentials, and the cookie attributes seem correctly configured. Yet, subsequent requests to /auth/validate don't carry the access_token cookie.

Here's the relevant backend code for setting the cookie:

```js
// NestJS Controller
@Post('login')
async signIn(@Body() signInDto: SignInDto, @Res() response: Response) {
  const { access_token } = await this.authService.signIn(signInDto.username, signInDto.password);
  response.cookie('access_token', access_token, {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
  });
  return response.sendStatus(200);
}
```

The CORS configuration is as follows:

```js
// main.ts
app.enableCors({
  origin: configService.get<string>('ALLOWED_ORIGINS').split(','), // Printed the split to the console and output was http://localhost:4200
  credentials: true,
});
```

And the Angular service that makes the login request:

```js
// Angular Service
async login(credentials: Login): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await privateRequest(REQUEST.POST, ENDPOINTS.AUTH.LOGIN, credentials);
    // The server should set the access_token in an HTTP-only cookie.
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(String(error));
  }
}
```

Result when requesting /auth/login with valid username and password:
[image: Successful http Request log to /auth/login]

The privateRequest function uses Axios and is configured with the withCredentials flag ([View package file here](https://github.com/Issue-Hub/issuehub-client/blob/develop/src/utils/http.ts)).

For additional context:

- The access_token is a JWT token.
- I've tested this on both Chrome and Firefox with the same outcome.
- The backend is running on http://localhost:3000.
- The frontend is running on http://localhost:4200.
- I'm not using HTTPS during development.

Could someone point out what I might be missing or doing wrong? Why isn't the browser saving the cookie?

Similar questions:

- [Browser is not saving cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612730/browser-is-not-saving-cookie)
- [Cookies headers are present but Cookies are not stored in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808537/cookies-headers-are-present-but-cookies-are-not-stored-in-browser)

Status: **Unresolved**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **secure** config from cookie to true:

```
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
```

The specs says that when sameSite is None, it must have Secure. With localhost (only) you can use it without https protocol. Or maybe use sameSite with *lax*.
This may fix the problem.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestions but it still didn't fix it. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the configs since the browser doesn't accept the cookie response.